# Why {...undefined} is not an error, but ...undefined is an error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

JavaScript，The fist line is error，the second line is right.

`console.log(...undefined) // error
console.log({...undefined}) // {}`

Comment: `console.log({...undefined})` in which environment does this actually not produce an error? chrome/firefox/nodejs/babel all complain about ... being unexpected

Comment: @JaromandaX Use babel.

Comment: @ANS - `chrome/firefox/nodejs/babel all complain about ... being unexpected` - what setting? ahhh, never mind ... any stage-*n* seems to work

Comment: @JaromandaX http://jsfiddle.net/GzYJ6/231/

Comment: `{...undefined}` is a json object, while `undefined` is well ....an error

Comment: `console.log(...undefined)` does not log error using `babel` within a function body if `undefined` is defined http://jsfiddle.net/GzYJ6/233/, http://jsfiddle.net/GzYJ6/234/

Answer (score 4):

```
console.log(...undefined) // error
```

is a standard ES6 spread, which requires the argument to be an iterable types. `undefined` is not iterable, thus you get an error.

```
console.log({...undefined})
```

is the proposed Object spread syntax. For this syntax, the argument passed in will have its properties copied into a new object. In this case, [the spec defines the following](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-object-rest-spread/#AbstractOperations-CopyDataProperties):

> 1. If source is `undefined` or `null`, let keys be a new empty List.

so that's why. In this case, it sees `undefined` as "copy nothing", so it is not an erroneous case.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` can be defined as an object or as a rest parameter, without `babel` being defined

```js
"use strict";

const fn = (...undefined) => 
             console.log(...undefined);

fn();

fn({b: 7});

fn({g: 9, x: 10});

fn({opts: "busted"})
```

Where `babel` is defined, using object rest

```js
   "use strict";

const fn = ({...undefined}) => 
             console.log({...undefined});

fn();

fn({b: 7});

fn({g: 9, x: 10});

fn({opts: "busted"})
```

Attempt to reproduce error where `babel` is defined and spread element precedes `undefined`

```js
"use strict";

const fn = ({...undefined}) => 
             console.log(...undefined); // no error

fn();

fn({b: 7});

fn({g: 9, x: 10});

fn({opts: "busted"})
```